# Entity Framewok recursive relation and childrens select

Tags: entity-framework-5, recursive-query

I'm using Entity Framework with Database First approach. I have a recursive relation of Categories related themselves with Offers entities.

**From a single Category i need to get all Offers including those of children categories.**

My model:
[image]

<s>My query:</s>

```
Dim category As Categories = DbContext.Categories.Include("Categories1").FirstOrDefault(Function(c) c.Id = 2)
Dim offers = category.Offers.Union(category.Categories1.SelectMany(Function(c) c.Offers))
```

This query give me the expected result but i want to know if there are other approaches more optimized

**EDIT:** My query was wrong because the relations aren't only 1 level deep

Comment: If the categories are only 1 level deep, this will do.

Comment: you're right, my query is wrong...